# How to debug C# WinForms application in VS 2008 Express on Wine?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-debugging, wine

Environment:
xUbuntu 18.04.4 LTS x64
wine-stable 5.0.0~bionic amd64 (winehq-stable + wine-stable-amd64 + wine-stable-i386:i386)
WINETRICKS_VERSION=20191224
(under wine WINEARCH=win32 + Visual Studio Express 2008 SP1 ENG(https://archive.org/details/vs2008sp1)  + dotnet35sp1 (was installed by winetrick))

In VS I created a Windows Forms Application -> build -> debug, and at this step I got the error message:

> error while trying to run project: unable to start program unknown error full-path-to-builded-exe-application-file.
>   operation not supported. unknown error: 0x80010115

(when I just run "build without debugging" - exe-application works fine!)

As I googl'ed, error code 0x80010115 means something like:

> public const int RPC_S_CALLPENDING = (int)(0x80010115 - 0x100000000);
>       /// 
>       /// OLE is waiting before retrying a request.
>       /// 
>       0x80010115, OLE has sent a request and is waiting for a reply.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

> How to debug C# WinForms application in VS 2008 Express on Wine?

Please try these steps:

**Suggestion**

**1)** close your VS Instance, delete `.suo` hidden file, `bin`, `obj` folder under the solution and then reopen your project again to test whether this issue persists.

**2)** disable `Enable Just My Code` option under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`General`.

**3)** You can also try to create a new empty Windows Forms Application to test whether the default project has the same issue. If so, I think there are some installation issues when you install VS2008 on Wine.

**Update 1**

After doing a deep research, although VS2008 can be installed on Wine, it still has several problems that don't work very well(unable to use start Debugging). See [this similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-can-i-install-visual-studio).

Also, you can also see the [Wine official website](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892) to list the performance about VS.

So when you install VS on wine, you can only pray for which part works.

**As a suggestion**, you can install [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which can be worked on it.

Comment: Thank you very much, but that did not help.
Yes, I know that 2008 is a very old version of VS, but this is the latest version that somehow works under Wine...

Comment: Did you create a new project have the same issue? Or please try to repair c# vs2008 under the setup program.

Comment: I repaired c# vs2008 under the setup program and created the new C#-project (and solution) but after debug executing I got the same error message. Maybe there are any other ideas?

Comment: After do some research, I think VS on Wine may have several problems that don't work very well  although it can be installed on Wine. But some tools of VS2008 probably did not work. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-can-i-install-visual-studio).